# How should I stop javascript to call the same function twice until it finishes with first call?

Tags: css-transitions

I am working on a image slider and using transitions in it. So, when I hit "next button" to get the next image in the middle of transition, the function gets called for next image, though the last transition affect hasn't done yet.

How should I stop the function to be called until the last transition completes? Please help! Thank You.

When I was working without transitions, it was working great but that wasn't smooth in mozilla, so I came up with transitions to make it! Now it is better than before but creating problems as transitions will take time to execute, and if in that time duration, I hit for next image, it calls the function for next transition effects.

Comment: Some sample code would be very useful here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called 'debouncing'. If you can use an external library, I would recommend to use [enter link description here](https://lodash.com/docs#debounce). Underscore provides a similar function.  This function ensures your function is not called twice and even can set a delay between two invocations.

If you can't then, you can google for a sample implementation like [this one](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) (I didn't test this one as I usually uses lodash's).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Pleasure. Not sure what you mean by 'break it', though.  If you want help with the code, feel free to show some.

Comment: I left some code for some minz but I felt like I got my ans, that's y I removed. I don't want to use any plugins to my website, do we have something inbuilt to do the same in javascript? and I am really very bad at designing, could you recommend something?

Comment: look at my second link: http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function.  If you want more help, post some code. Otherwise, i think this answered your original question.